# How to draw a translucent image on a form?

Tags: delphi, transparency, delphi-7, alphablending

I want to a draw a translucent image on a Delphi form, but for some reason it is not working.

Here is the original PNG (border is semi transparent):
[image: Transparent border]

I load the image in a `TImage` object:

```
Image1.Transparent := True;
Form1.Color := clWhite;
Form1.TransparentColor := True;
Form1.TransparentColorValue := clWhite;
```

[image: TImage]

The application:
[image: Application]

The image isn't translucent. I am working with a BMP image that contains the alpha channel. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't understand how you could use a PNG image in a Delphi 7 `TImage` control. Delphi 7 does not support PNG...

Comment: hmmmmm. It loads as PNGObject.

Comment: D7 doesn't support png. You have installed 3rd party component. Why are you against 3rd party components?

Comment: OK, with thir party components! ooooo. Sorry i am using TNT Unicode controls. TTntImage.

Comment: @Robrok: Your English is not a problem, but it is a bit confusing when you say that you are using `TImage` but in fact is using a `TntImage`!

Comment: Thanks!! But c`mon with the problem!

Comment: @Robrok: Actually, I am working on it as we speak!

Comment: I am searchin Web but with no results.

Comment: @Robrok: I have found a solution.

Comment: @Robrok Does you use of TNT mean you gave up on writing your own Unicode button control? If so that was a good move!

Comment: I have create my own button named TSuperButton. :D With 3 button states. Finally!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution that will let you draw a BMP image with an alpha channel onto a form using only the Windows API:

```
const
  AC_SRC_OVER = 0;
  AC_SRC_ALPHA = 1;

type
  BLENDFUNCTION = packed record
    BlendOp,
    BlendFlags,
    SourceConstantAlpha,
    AlphaFormat: byte;
  end;

function WinAlphaBlend(hdcDest: HDC; xoriginDest, yoriginDest, wDest, hDest: integer;
  hdcSrc: HDC; xoriginSrc, yoriginSrc, wSrc, hSrc: integer; ftn: BLENDFUNCTION): LongBool;
  stdcall; external 'Msimg32.dll' name 'AlphaBlend';

procedure TForm4.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  hbm: HBITMAP;
  bm: BITMAP;
  bf: BLENDFUNCTION;
  dc: HDC;
begin
  hbm := LoadImage(0,
    'C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Skrivbord\RatingCtrl.bmp',
    IMAGE_BITMAP,
    0,
    0,
    LR_LOADFROMFILE);
  if hbm = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    if GetObject(hbm, sizeof(bm), @bm) = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
    dc := CreateCompatibleDC(0);
    if dc = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      if SelectObject(dc, hbm) = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
      bf.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
      bf.BlendFlags := 0;
      bf.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
      bf.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;
      if not WinAlphaBlend(Canvas.Handle,
        10,
        10,
        bm.bmWidth,
        bm.bmHeight,
        dc,
        0,
        0,
        bm.bmWidth,
        bm.bmHeight,
        bf) then RaiseLastOSError;
    finally
      DeleteDC(dc);
    end;
  finally
    DeleteObject(hbm);
  end;
end;
```

Using The GIMP, I converted the PNG image

[image]

found [here](https://privat.rejbrand.se/RatingCtrl.png) to a 32-bit RGBA bitmap, found [here](https://privat.rejbrand.se/RatingCtrl.bmp), and the result is very good:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, it works. But if i want to draw a border around the form?

Comment: I want to create skinable form.

Comment: Nice! BTW, your code works with the regular gdi function declaration, i.e. `windows.AlphaBlend()`, no need to declare the constants, the record and the function..

Comment: @Sertac: I am very well aware of that, but I am not sure if `AlphaBlend` is declared in the `Windows.pas` that ships with the old Delphi 7, the Delphi version of the OP. In addition, the declaration of `AlphaBlend` in `Windows.pas` in Delphi 2009 (my Delphi version) is very 'ugly': `function AlphaBlend(DC: HDC; p2, p3, p4, p5: Integer; DC6: HDC; p7, p8, p9, p10: Integer; p11: TBlendFunction): BOOL; stdcall;` But I guess I should have written a footnote about this.

Comment: And why in the world is every post I make at SO downvoted?!?!

Answer (score 1):

The `TransparentColorValue` approach cannot possibly work, because this only works with images in which a single colour represents full transparency. [In addition, you are toying with the *form's* transparent colour instead of *image's* transparent colour!] The above PNG image is supposed to have an *alpha channel*, so it's not like every pixel is either shown or transparent -- instead, each pixel has an opacity between 0 and 1 (0.37, for instance). That is, in addition to the R, G, and B components of each pixel, there is an 'alpha' component A.

The above image appears to be corrupt, however. A 'correct' PNG is shown below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [rejbrand.se](https://privat.rejbrand.se/RatingCtrl.png))</sub>

You can try to blend the above one onto different backgrounds, and you will find that the shadow blends nicely.

So, if one has a 'correct' PNG, how to draw it onto a form? Well, that is going to be very difficult in your case, since Delphi 7 does not support PNG images. It only supports BMP images, and these normally do not have alpha channels.

Comment: windows bitmaps often have alpha channels

Comment: @David: Yeah, but I am not sure if the Delphi 7 `TImage` can handle those. Can it?

Comment: what do you mean by often David?  Very few tools support .BMP files with alpha channels, so how often, do you suppose, that a stored windows .BMP has one? I would say close to 0.0001% of them have them. Except maybe on your computer.

Comment: @andreas no I doubt it very much. Delphi's TBitmap has been very tardy with alpha support.

Comment: I can save this image as BMP but the image will be black. :(

Comment: @warren who said anything about files? How do you think 32bpp xp icons are represented inside your computer?

Comment: @Robrok: The one titled 'Form4' above?  Then you are probably using a very bad image file format converter. Try Paint. But still, BMP and alpha channels do not go together very well, so I would probably not use BMP if I were you.

Comment: BMP or PNG, what ever. I am learning and i want to paint transparent image on a form.

Comment: I like alpha skins but they not free. And older versions are bad.

Comment: @David: The OP said something about files. This is a site where we answer the questions the user asked.  Or we try to.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try do draw your png onto new image with regular bmp. Draw what you want onto image 2 and redraw /or assign/ all to your image 1 when finish. Must works...